# LogisticRegression: Unknown label type: 'continuous' using sklearn in python

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have the following code to test some of most popular ML algorithms of sklearn python library:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn                        import metrics, svm
from sklearn.linear_model           import LinearRegression
from sklearn.linear_model           import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree                   import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors              import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis  import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.naive_bayes            import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm                    import SVC

trainingData    = np.array([ [2.3, 4.3, 2.5],  [1.3, 5.2, 5.2],  [3.3, 2.9, 0.8],  [3.1, 4.3, 4.0]  ])
trainingScores  = np.array( [3.4, 7.5, 4.5, 1.6] )
predictionData  = np.array([ [2.5, 2.4, 2.7],  [2.7, 3.2, 1.2] ])

clf = LinearRegression()
clf.fit(trainingData, trainingScores)
print("LinearRegression")
print(clf.predict(predictionData))

clf = svm.SVR()
clf.fit(trainingData, trainingScores)
print("SVR")
print(clf.predict(predictionData))

clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(trainingData, trainingScores)
print("LogisticRegression")
print(clf.predict(predictionData))

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(trainingData, trainingScores)
print("DecisionTreeClassifier")
print(clf.predict(predictionData))

clf = KNeighborsClassifier()
clf.fit(trainingData, trainingScores)
print("KNeighborsClassifier")
print(clf.predict(predictionData))

clf = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
clf.fit(trainingData, trainingScores)
print("LinearDiscriminantAnalysis")
print(clf.predict(predictionData))

clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(trainingData, trainingScores)
print("GaussianNB")
print(clf.predict(predictionData))

clf = SVC()
clf.fit(trainingData, trainingScores)
print("SVC")
print(clf.predict(predictionData))
```

The first two works ok, but I got the following error in `LogisticRegression` call:

```
root@ubupc1:/home/ouhma# python stack.py 
LinearRegression
[ 15.72023529   6.46666667]
SVR
[ 3.95570063  4.23426243]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack.py", line 28, in <module>
    clf.fit(trainingData, trainingScores)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py", line 1174, in fit
    check_classification_targets(y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py", line 172, in check_classification_targets
    raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

The input data is the same as in the previous calls, so what is going on here?

And by the way, why there is a huge diference in the first prediction of `LinearRegression()` and `SVR()` algorithms `(15.72 vs 3.95)`?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You are passing floats to a classifier which expects categorical values as the target vector. If you convert it to `int` it will be accepted as input (although it will be questionable if that's the right way to do it).

It would be better to  convert your training scores by using scikit's [`labelEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) function.

The same is true for your DecisionTree and KNeighbors qualifier.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import utils

lab_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoded = lab_enc.fit_transform(trainingScores)
>>> array([1, 3, 2, 0], dtype=int64)

print(utils.multiclass.type_of_target(trainingScores))
>>> continuous

print(utils.multiclass.type_of_target(trainingScores.astype('int')))
>>> multiclass

print(utils.multiclass.type_of_target(encoded))
>>> multiclass
```

Comment: Thank you! So I've got to convert `2.3` to `23` and so on, isn't it? There is a elegant way to make this conversion using numpy or pandas?

Comment: But, in this example the input data has float numbers using LogisticRegression function: http://machinelearningmastery.com/compare-machine-learning-algorithms-python-scikit-learn/ ... and it works ok. Why?

Comment: The input can be floats but the output need to be categorical, i.e. int. Column 8 is only 0 or 1 in this example.
Usually it is the other way round that you have categorical labels, e.g. ['red', 'big', 'sick'] and you need to convert it numerical values. Try http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features or http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html

Comment: Are `2.3` and `23` same?

Comment: why categorical on regression?

Answer (score 69):

`LogisticRegression` is not for *regression* but **classification** !

The `Y` variable must be the classification class,

(for example `0` or `1`)

And not a `continuous` variable,

that would be a *regression* problem.

Comment: I hope this is not spam but I ended up here many times and the error promt is not very intuitive.

Comment: this should be the correct answer. Indeed LogisticRegression is a classifier. Hence the error.

Comment: That's generally true, but sometimes you want to benefit from Sigmoid mapping the output to [0,1] during optimization. If you use least squares on a given output range, while training, your model will be penalized for extrapolating, e.g., if it predicts `1.2` for some sample, it would be penalized the same way as for predicting `0.8`. This constraint might distract the optimization from the objective. Sigmoid allows you to extrapolate with no penalty, so the model could say either `10` or `100` and Sigmoid will anyway turn it to almost 1. There is essence in continuous logistic regression.

Comment: plus it's a linear transformation (scale + bias) from any given range to [0,1] and vice versa, so you can always "normalize" your labels to [0,1] while training and remap them to the given range at inference. Note that if you use an iterative optimization of least-squares with your custom loss function (i.e., rather than using the pseudo-inverse algorithm), then you may be able to trim the model output prior to computing the cost and thus address the extrapolation penalization problem without logistic regression.

Answer (score 35):

I struggled with the same issue when trying to feed floats to the classifiers. I wanted to keep floats and not integers for accuracy. Try using regressor algorithms. For example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn import svm

classifiers = [
    svm.SVR(),
    linear_model.SGDRegressor(),
    linear_model.BayesianRidge(),
    linear_model.LassoLars(),
    linear_model.ARDRegression(),
    linear_model.PassiveAggressiveRegressor(),
    linear_model.TheilSenRegressor(),
    linear_model.LinearRegression()]

trainingData    = np.array([ [2.3, 4.3, 2.5],  [1.3, 5.2, 5.2],  [3.3, 2.9, 0.8],  [3.1, 4.3, 4.0]  ])
trainingScores  = np.array( [3.4, 7.5, 4.5, 1.6] )
predictionData  = np.array([ [2.5, 2.4, 2.7],  [2.7, 3.2, 1.2] ])

for item in classifiers:
    print(item)
    clf = item
    clf.fit(trainingData, trainingScores)
    print(clf.predict(predictionData),'\n')
```