# ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous' while using Logistical Regression

Tags: python, python-3.x, roc

I'm using Logistical Regression to plot ROC. I'm using this code to pull data.

```
Diabetes=pd.read_csv('datasource/ScoringDatasheet.csv', sep=';')
```

Then I'm using `iloc` like this.

```
inputData=Diabetes.iloc[:,:60]
outputData=Diabetes.iloc[:,60]
```

Then I'm using `logistical regression` to analyze the data and plot `ROC`

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logit1=LogisticRegression()
logit1.fit(inputData,outputData)

logit1.score(inputData,outputData)



np.mean(logit1.predict(inputData)==outputData)

trueInput=Diabetes.ix[Diabetes['Outcome']==1].iloc[:,:62]
trueOutput=Diabetes.ix[Diabetes['Outcome']==1].iloc[:,62]

np.mean(logit1.predict(trueInput)==trueOutput)

falseInput=Diabetes.ix[Diabetes['Outcome']==0].iloc[:,:62]
falseOutput=Diabetes.ix[Diabetes['Outcome']==0].iloc[:,62]

np.mean(logit1.predict(falseInput)==falseOutput)





from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, roc_curve, roc_auc_score
confusion_matrix(logit1.predict(inputData),outputData)


fpr, tpr,_=roc_curve(logit1.predict(inputData),outputData,drop_intermediate=False)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color='red', lw=2, label='ROC curve')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='blue', lw=2, linestyle='--')
plt.xlabel('False Positive ')
plt.ylabel('True Positive ')
plt.title('ROC curve')
plt.show()


roc_auc_score(logit1.predict(inputData),outputData)

coef_DF=pd.DataFrame(data={'Variable':list(inputData),
'value':(logit1.coef_[0])})

coef_DF_standardised=pd.DataFrame(data={'Variable':list(inputData),
'value':(logit1.coef_[0])*np.std(inputData,axis=0)/np.std(outputData)})

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(inputData.iloc[:,1],inputData.iloc[:,5],c=logit1.predict_proba(inputData)[:,1],alpha=0.4)
plt.xlabel('Glucose level ')
plt.ylabel('BMI ')
plt.show()

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(inputData.iloc[:,1],inputData.iloc[:,5],c=outputData,alpha=0.4)
plt.xlabel('Glucose level ')
plt.ylabel('BMI ')
plt.show()
```

But when I run my code, I get below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                             File "index.py", line 13, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                                          logit1.fit(inputData,outputData)                                                                                                                                                                                                           File "C:\Users\kulkaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py", line 1221, in fit                                                                                                         check_classification_targets(y)                                                                                                                                                                                                            File "C:\Users\kulkaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 171, in check_classification_targets                                                                                      raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)                                                                                                                                                                                      ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

According to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41925157/logisticregression-unknown-label-type-continuous-using-sklearn-in-python), I should convert `floats` to `categorical values` if I'm using classifier. But I'm using regression here, how can I fix that error?
A part of data set that I'm using is given below:

```
Pat_ID  Demo1   Demo2   Demo3   Demo4   Demo5   Demo6   DisHis1 DisHis1Times    DisHis2 DisHis2Times    DisHis3 DisHis3Times    DisHis4 DisHis5 DisHis6 DisHis7 DisStage1   DisStage2   LungFun1    LungFun2    LungFun3    LungFun4    LungFun5    LungFun6    LungFun7    LungFun8    LungFun9    LungFun10   LungFun11   LungFun12   LungFun13   LungFun14   LungFun15   LungFun16   LungFun17   LungFun18   LungFun19   LungFun20   Dis1    Dis1Treat   Dis2    Dis2Times   Dis3    Dis3Times   Dis4    Dis4Treat   Dis5    Dis5Treat   Dis6    Dis6Treat   Dis7    RespQues1   ResQues1a   ResQues1b   ResQues1c   ResQues2a   SmokHis1    SmokHis2    SmokHis3    SmokHis4
6   0   0.430159833 0.596541787 0.323296661 0   0.867768595 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.8 0.714285714 0.447443182 0.280725319 0.392405063 0.315347722 0.442765731 0.35344 0.306497788 0.078249895 0.230895645 0   0.175430575 0.776595745 0.194322248 0.123935854 0.792696843 0.873987854 0.803933254 0.528064786 1   0.1 0   0   0   0   0.333333333 0.15    0   0   0   0   0.333333333 1   0   0.273565574 0.1074  0.7282  0.0469  0.3 0.082352941 0.085237258 0.724137931 0.145833333
9   0   0.218902015 0.484149856 0.177957923 0   0.225895317 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.6 0.142857143 0.899147727 0.441235729 0.620253165 0.708333333 0.69303235  0.55904 0.532922703 0.263357173 0.718707204 0.729159016 0.65096784  0.64893617  0.385594463 0.234804989 0.613921643 0.409665992 0.483313468 0.115610165 0   0.5 0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0.333333333 1   0   0.456557377 0.1791  0.7896  0.3212  0.2 0.176470588 0.144991213 0.620689655 0
15  0   0.628908965 0.433717579 0.594093804 1   0.363636364 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.142857143 0.970170455 0.396910678 0.746835443 0.575239808 0.478848205 0.36944 0.565368266 0.309002945 0.569433032 0.463643041 0.425392471 0.787234043 0.427004516 0.290833498 0.652339293 0.484311741 0.511323004 0.138788048 0   0.6 0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0.333333333 1   0   0.396413934 0.2596  0.8032  0.1836  0.2 0.058823529 0.052724077 0.637931034 0.0625
25  1   0.236275191 0.268011527 0.280254777 0   0.388429752 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.6 0   0.721590909 0.39758227  0.53164557  0.363309353 0.394063278 0.31088 0.224863364 0.096339924 0.321007943 0.351817848 0.361377839 0.521276596 0.213208986 0.059196199 0.728413846 0.497975709 0.62932062  0.147165596 1   0.6 0   0   1   0   0.333333333 0.05    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.1 0.176470588 0.118629174 0.517241379 0.104166667
27  1   0.397498263 0.327089337 0.425786528 0   0.063360882 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.950284091 0.358629953 0.82278481  0.580035971 0.462851049 0.33696 0.40426824  0.508834666 0.594631608 0.491737055 0.431489102 0.819148936 0.372514517 0.373589388 0.623430962 0.422823887 0.489272944 0.114493158 0   0.9 0   0   0.333333333 0.020833333 0.333333333 0.05    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.058709016 0   0.1847  0   0   0.176470588 0.087873462 0.396551724 0.0625
28  1   0.510771369 0.452449568 0.468249373 0   0.027548209 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0.142857143 0.928977273 0.392209537 0.746835443 0.648081535 0.547813722 0.4232  0.46777132  0.379259571 0.675431389 0.581894969 0.502362445 0.79787234  0.351398909 0.388437933 0.597565614 0.441548583 0.472586412 0.122591455 0   0.9 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0.480840164 0.5239  0.5354  0.4146  0.1 0.411764706 0.156414763 0.272413793 0
36  1   0.385684503 0.341498559 0.405134144 0   0.195592287 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.6 0.142857143 0.737215909 0.36937542  0.594936709 0.43735012  0.455563455 0.33952 0.259651254 0.165124106 0.447274719 0.432611091 0.384545039 0.691489362 0.212387823 0.159176401 0.647014074 0.504807692 0.511918951 0.148841106 0   0.8 1   0   0.333333333 0.041666667 0.333333333 0.1 0.333333333 0   1   0   1   0   1   0.453790984 0.5014  0.5946  0.3379  0.2 0.117647059 0.077768014 0.515517241 0
```

Comment: Any python developer here who can answer this question?

Answer (score 1):

`sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` is a classifier (not a regressor) according to http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html.

Comment: @AjayKulkarni Use regressor to solve regression problem. To choose one you may start with sklearn cheat-sheet (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html).