# ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous' Error in SVM

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, svm

I got an error while running the code below. I've tried every solution I found but they didn't work.

The error is

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

and here's my code:

```
random_state=0
classifier = SVC(kernel='linear', random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I got this error on:

```
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

[example input](https://ibb.co/Kr1cZf0)

The `state` is the dependent variable and `k` is the independent variable. So I would like to train these. My main purpose is to estimate the state information according to the new `k` variable. I'm not using an index for the training. `X` and `Y` sets are equal to 'k' and 'state'.

Comment: Can you show some of your input data?

Comment: Are you passing floats instead of ints?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41925957/6361531

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very hard to say why you are getting this error without looking at the data.

However, my first guess is that you must be passing non integer value as label, in heading of state it says 0/1 but I am not sure if that's the case.

I'd suggest you 2 options.

1. Explicitly convert the datatype to `int32` using `astype()` function.
2. Use `LabelEncoder` to encode your output variable.