# Scikit-Learn Logistic Regression is Inaccurate

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, logistic-regression

I was using `scikit-learn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`, but it didn't work so well.

I started with an x and y list. X was integers between -10 and 10 inclusive. Y was the x value plugged into the logistic function `100/  (1 + e^-x)`. This means it should have been a perfect Logistic Regression.

It worked well, but when I changed the Y slightly (+1, -1, or 0 for every y value), it didn't work. When plotted with `matplotlib.pyplot` it was clearly a logistic curve.

I tried

`reg = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=10e4)
reg.fit(x, y)
reg.predict(x)`

The predicted Y had half the points at the minimum y (y=0), and the other half at the maximum (y=100). 
I tried with C as the default value, but the same thing happened.

Why is this, and how do I get a correct regression model?

**Also:**
[image: Orange is the model, blue is the actual. This one is a little bit better, but when C is default, all oranges are above 100 or less than 0]

Orange is the model, blue is the actual. This one is a little bit better, but when C is default, all oranges are above 100 or less than 0

Comment: Since LogisticRegression is used for categorization, your code predicts your categories in y which are derived from your floats resulting from 100/  (1 + e^-x) , right?. If you rather want to do regression, you can find good code examples in the link below.
In order to understand the impact of the regularization parameter C (if you really want this), you need to share how your categories look like that are created from the float.


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41925157/logisticregression-unknown-label-type-continuous-using-sklearn-in-python

Comment: @andi I thought that since it was LogisticRegression, it would do Regression. For the C value, I used the default on a perfect Logistic curve. When it didn't work, I googled and it said to use a large C value, so I used C=10e4.

Comment: @AndiSchroff     Also, I used integers, not floats, so the link isn't really what I'm looking for. I tries `linear_model.BayesianRidge`, but that didn't work well with Logistic curves. Is there something in linear_model for logistic **regression** and not classification?