# Pandas returns this: ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am having trouble when using pandas and sklearn for machine learning. My problem is

> ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'

I tried

```
model = sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)
```

and it returns this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-3caead2f350b> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(ninp, out)

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    888         """
    889 
--> 890         super().fit(
    891             X, y,
    892             sample_weight=sample_weight,

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    179 
    180         if is_classification:
--> 181             check_classification_targets(y)
    182             y = np.copy(y)
    183 

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    170     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    171                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
--> 172         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
    173 
    174 

ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

Comment: It might be helpful to now what `X` and `y` contain? Maybe add a short example which helps to understand their structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LogisticRegression: Unknown label type: 'continuous' using sklearn in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41925157/logisticregression-unknown-label-type-continuous-using-sklearn-in-python)

Comment: You need to check what your target is, most probably it's float. In this case you may think about switching to regression or check other numerous answers already given on SO in similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

A classifier classifies a set of examples into discrete classes (i.e. it assigns a label corresponding to one of K classes). If your target (the content of your `y` variable) is continuous (for example a float ranging between 0 and 1), then the decision tree does not know what to do with it.

You have 2 solutions:

1. Your problem is a classification task and you need to model your target variable so that it represents categories and not a continuous variable
2. Your problem is **not** a classification task, it is a regression task and you need to use the appropriate models (e.g. `DecisionTreeRegressor`)