# Can you use GridSearchCV on continuous data?

Tags: python, data-science, gridsearchcv, gbm

I'm working on a gradient boosting model and wanted to apply `GridSearchCV` to it but I am getting this error: `ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'`. My data is all continuous.  All of the suggestions I have seen have been to transform my `y_train` using `LabelEncoder()` but this is a regression problem so I don't see the need in doing that.  I am using the Boston Housing dataset from Kaggle if that helps at all.

Also, I have used `GridSearchCV` on a random forest model with the same data and it works.  Not sure why it works on one but not the other.

```
# doesn't work for this one
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier, GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

gbc = GradientBoostingClassifier()

parameters = {
    "n_estimators" : [5 , 50, 250, 500],
    "max_depth" : [1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
    "learning_rate" : [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]
}

cv = GridSearchCV(gbc, parameters, cv=5)
cv.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
```

```
# Works for this one
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

tree = DecisionTreeRegressor()

model = GridSearchCV(tree, param_grid={'max_depth': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}, cv=5)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# get metrics
print(model.best_params_)
print(model.best_score_)
```

Comment: Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41925157/logisticregression-unknown-label-type-continuous-using-sklearn-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `GradientBoostClassifier()` for regression tasks. As the name suggests this model is only for classification tasks. What you need instead is the [GradientBoostRegressor()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html). Seems like you imported both but just called the wrong one.

(In the Decision Tree case you correctly specified `DecisionTreeRegressor()` and not `DecisionTreeClassifier()`)

Comment: Did this answer help? If so can you consider accepting it pls?